# and two predicate functions in c++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, predicate

I am looking for a way to create a binary operation between two predicate functions. This is my predicate function declaration:

```
template <typename T>
using Predicate = std::function<bool(T const&)>;
```

I am looking for a way to 'concat' two predicate functions into one:

```
template <typename T>
static Predicate<T> andPredicate(Predicate<T> a, Predicate<T> b) {
   // ???
}
```

Expected behaviour:

```
Predicate<int> a = [](int a) { return a < 5; };
Predicate<int> b = [](int a) { return a > 0; };

Predicate<int> c = andPredicate(a, b); // a < 5 && a > 0

int number = 3;
bool result = c(number);
```

Is something like this possible in C++?

Comment: Why is it static?

Comment: You need to return a functionoid that, when called, will itself call `a` and `b` (which it has previously stored) with its own parameter and return the `and` of their results. You're not far ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use a lambda:

```
template <typename T>
Predicate<T> andPredicate(Predicate<T> a, Predicate<T> b) {
    return [=](T i) { return a(i) && b(i); };
}
```

You can even avoid the extra overhead of `std::function` by leveraging templates:

```
template <typename P1, typename P2>
auto andPredicate(P1&& a, P2&& b) {
    return [a = std::forward<P1>(a), b = std::forward<P2>(b)](const auto& i) {
        return a(i) && b(i);
    };
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/366bac0cfd8e4d3d)

This avoids the extra type-erasure overhead of `std::function` by accepting the actual types needed for the original predicates and returning the lambda directly.  You can then store that in a `std::function` if you need, or just let the compiler deduce the type with `auto`.

Comment: @Slava oops, yep, fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It would be interesting to create `predicateCombiner` and create `andPredicate` using `predicateCombiner` and `std::logical_and`

Comment: @Slava Sure, [you could do that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2e873cced933ff8), but I don't think it really buys much in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
template <typename T>
static Predicate<T> andPredicate(Predicate<T> a, Predicate<T> b) {
   return [a,b]( T const &val ) { return a( val ) and b( val ) };
}
```

it is not clear why you want to make it static though.